# Find dropped rows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame of roughly 64,000 rows. It looks roughly like this:

```
               values
asn   country
12345 US       ...
12345 MX       ...
```

I was running into an error saying that the MultiIndex could not contain non-unique values. This lead me to suspect that I had some `NaN` value in my index. So I tried the following to verify:

```
df = # my data frame
rows = df.shape[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.dropna())
if df.shape[0] < rows:
    print "Dropped %s NaN rows!" % (rows - df.shape[0])
```

As expected, this printed out "Dropped 10 NaN rows!"... although now I'd like to find out **which** rows were dropped so I can investigate how they got into my DataFrame in the first place.

How can I do this? I've tried looking through the Pandas docs for something like `df.index.isna()` (no dice) and I've tried taking the "before" and "after" data frames and computing their difference, but wasn't sure how to do this and my attempts led to indexing errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html) to get a `DataFrame` equivalent to your index, then combine [`isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) to determine the null rows:

```
idxr = df.index.to_frame().isna().any(axis=1)
```

You can now use this to filter your `DataFrame` via `df[idxr]` to restrict to rows with a null value in the `MultiIndex`.

Note: with older versions of pandas you will need to use `isnull` instead of `isna`.